# Donde esta el error en mi consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Porque se me altera el orden? Para sql el 10 y 12 no es mas grande que 2?

```
$decada = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT link, disco_artista, disco_titulo, fecha from musica where genero LIKE '%{$variable}%' AND fecha BETWEEN '1990' AND '1999' order by case when disco_artista = 'Varios' then disco_titulo else disco_artista end, fecha");

Rock vol. 1
Rock vol. 10
Rock vol. 11
Rock vol. 2
Rock vol. 3
Rock vol. 4
...
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el diseño de tú base de datos o las tablas donde haces referencias a cada uno de esos campos?

Comment: disco_titulo y disco_artista  estan en varchar donde disco_titulo contiene "Rock vol. 1" o "Rock vol. 10"

Answer (score 1):

Comúnmente pasa esto porque los datos donde tienes almacenado el numero 1,10,11,2,3,4 tiene el tipo string en la base de datos (varchar o char) cambia el tipo de dato por un integer (int).

Si lo tienes en tipo de datos integer utiliza Order By, en el nombre de columna donde estan almacenados los datos: 1,10,11,2,3,4

Comment: Concuerdo con Antoni, hace un tiempo tuve el mismo problema y se debía a que almacenaba esos datos como Strings y no como Int lo cual es totalmente distinto a la hora de evaluar.